# When calculating the percentile manually, the 25th percentile is 14 for the dataset but when using NumPy it is 14.5

Tags: numpy, statistics, percentile

[image]

Image for reference.
When calculating the percentile manually, the 25th percentile is 14 for the dataset but when using NumPy it is 14.5.

Answer (score 2):

As you yourself found, the 25th percentile of your data corresponds to element 2.75, which is not an integer. You explicitly chose to round the index rather than to interpolate the values.

Numpy, by default, [linearly interpolates](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html). You can pass a different choice of interpolation method using the `method` kwarg of np.percentile.